# Return statement within a map with items: within Flutter DropdownButton, Why and How it works

Tags: dart, flutter, dropdownbutton

I am new to Flutter and Dart. I'm following a free tutorial but I am confused how there is a return statement within map in items: in a DropdownButton. How does that work? I'm looking for clarification as to why the return statement is there and to where is it sending its value.

I have tried to lookup how a return statement is within a map but I may be mistaken on how to ask this question. The code works as given but I am not sure how it works. Is there a step by step simplified form of this code that may lead to more of an understanding. As it is now "it's over my head."

```
          DropdownButton<String>(

            items: _currencies.map(
                    (String dropDownStringItem) {

                   // interested in this return statement 
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: dropDownStringItem,
                    child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                  );
                }
            ).toList(),  //convert to List


            onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
              _onDropDownItemSelected(newValueSelected);
            },

            value: _currentItemSelected,
          ),
```

Comment: If either of the answers were useful to you, you should accept one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The naming might be confusing for someone new but let me explain for you a bit the code you've posted:

So the `DropdownButton` constructor expect a list of `DropdownMenuItem` as parameter, but in your case you don't have a list of `DropdownMenuItem` you have a list of `String`. What you need is a way to transform a String to a `DropdownMenuItem`, the easiest way would be to do a `for` over the strings, create a new `DropdownMenuItem` for each `String` you have, add it into a list and then send it to the `DropdownButton`. Something like:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem> newGenerated = [];
_currencies.forEach((value) {
    DropdownMenuItem newItem = DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: dropDownStringItem,
                                  child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                                 );
    newGenerated.add(newItem)
}
 DropdownButton<String>(
        items: newGenerated,  //convert to List
        onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
          _onDropDownItemSelected(newValueSelected);
        },
        value: _currentItemSelected,
      ),
```

The above code does the same thing as the code you have, but in my opinion is not that nice.

The function that you're using `map` is used to transform a list of objects into an `Iterable` of other elements applying a function on every element of the list that would be transformed.

One thing to keep in mind, map transforms into an `Iterable` and not a List(you can't cast `Iterable` to `List`), fortunately `Iterable` has another method called `toList()` that will transform it into a `List`.

Now in your case, the list that has to be transformed is `_currencies`, the function that is applied:

```
 (String dropDownStringItem) {

                   // interested in this return statement 
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: dropDownStringItem,
                    child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                  );
```

The `dropDownStringItem` will take value of each element in the `_currencies`. 
The `return DropdownMenuItem ...` will return the transformed object

Hope that this helps.